# angular-websocket is working

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, websocket

I have included angular-websocket.js by directly downloading from [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-websocket) (third option-**Downloading it manually by clicking here to download development unminified version**)

Now if I inject "ngWebsocket" in module, then inject modullr error is coming, then I tried by injecting "angular-websocket". Now it's working.

But again in the .run(), I am trying to open new websocket connection.
For that I inject $websocket and creating new connection with $websocket.$new object. Here again new error throwing **undefined is not a function** on $new.

Here is my code:

```
var modules     = ["ui.router", "ui.bootstrap", "ui.bootstrap.tpls", "ui.bootstrap.modal", "ui.bootstrap.popover", "ngStorage", "angular-websocket"];

var app         = angular.module('app', modules);

app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $sessionStorage, $window, loginService, $websocket){

    var ws = $websocket.$new('ws://localhost:12345'); // instance of ngWebsocket, handled by $websocket service

    ws.$on('$open', function () {
        console.log('Oh my gosh, websocket is really open! Fukken awesome!');

        ws.$emit('ping', 'hi listening websocket server'); // send a message to the websocket server

        var data = {
            level: 1,
            text: 'ngWebsocket rocks!',
            array: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
            nested: {
                level: 2,
                deeper: [{
                    hell: 'yeah'
                }, {
                    so: 'good'
                }]
            }
        };

        ws.$emit('pong', data);
    });
})
```

I am referring the following link: https://github.com/wilk/ng-websocket

Help !
Thanks !

Comment: you should write `ngWebsocket` in `var modules = [...]` not the `angular-websocket`

Comment: if I am writing ngWebsocket then injection error is coming... Please note that I am not using any npm or bower to install websocket. I directly downloaded the angular-websocket.min.js and included in the application.

could this create a problem?

Comment: no there is no problem. but keep mind that respective js file must be included in your index.html

Answer (score 0):

- Why you put it in run method? Try to do it like this example:
  https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-websocket/blob/master/example/scripts.js
- Why you have invoke a $new method. Try following:

  `var ws = $websocket('ws://localhost:16161');`
- Double check if you have include the 'xxx/angular-websocket/dist/angular-websocket.js' in your index.html